# How do I send to multiple recipients in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am learning how to use Ruby on Rails and I am having difficulties sending an email to multiple users. I created a simple rails app. The code I have actually sends the emails, but both emails are not copied in the same email. In other words User1 does not see User2 email or vice versa. My question is

**"How do I get User1 and User2 to see each other when they get the email?"**

Here is the code in my user_mailer.rb file:

```
def email1(user1, user2)
    @user1 = User.find_by(email: "myyahooemail@yahoo.com")
    @user2 = User.find_by(email: "mygmailemail@gmail.com")
    mail(to: "#{@user1.email}, #{@user2.email}",
        subject: 'Testing sending emails to 2 people',
        body: 'The email should have both users in the TO field')
end
```

Here is the code in my users_controller.rb file:

```
def send_email1
   UserMailer.email1(@user1, @user2).deliver
   redirect_to users_path
end
```

Here is the code in my routes.rb file:

```
get 'sendemail1' => 'users#send_email1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can simply set the list of emails to the `:to` key.

```
mail(to: [@user1.email, @user2.email],
      subject: 'Testing sending emails to 2 people',
      body: 'The email should have both users in the TO field')
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cc: key to achieve what you want. [As explained here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

```
 mail(to: "#{@user1.email}",
      cc: "#{@user2.email}"
      subject: 'Testing sending emails to 2 people',
      body: 'The email should have both users in the TO field')
```

`obs:` `cc:` can take a string or an array of addresses.

Comment: Unfortunately the code didn't work. I had to add a comma to the end of the cc line of code, but still it didn't work. I don't know why. I appreciate your help.